# How to stop Navigating to Record Detail Page

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

How to stop Navigating to Record Detail Page after creating new Record through Lightning web component

Below is the code i am using

```
          handleNewListView(){

       this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]
           ({

         type: 'standard__objectPage',

          attributes: 
           {
            objectApiName: 'CustListView__c',
            actionName: 'new'
        }
    });

}
```

But it is navigating to record detail page after creating a record and 
i do not want to navigate to record detail page after creating new record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such event which you can listen and handle it when you are using **[standard__objectPage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_page_reference_type)** navigation.

As a workaround, You can use [Lightning data service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_ui_api) to create a record form and control the behaviour.